# How to export full mysql database with php script...? Problem in using 'mysqldump'

Tags: php, mysql

i am using this command to backup my full mysql database..

```
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';
$command = "mysqldump -h$hostname -u$username -p$password $dbname > $backupFile";
system($command);
```

I am getting blank file.
And i am using XAMMP on windows.
I have already used `exec()` but also getting blank file.
And but on shell it has successfully done.
Whats wrong in this code.

Comment: try adding the full path to mysqldump

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `system`. You should. Because you're worth it.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting blank file. Where is it located?

Comment: @shakti m sure m geting blank file...and it is located in the root directory.

Comment: @nikc wt should i return the value either o or 1..

Comment: @dagon i need to do this byscript if i do add full path then wt would be the path on server..bcoz its c:\xampp\mysql in my pc windows and wt would be the full path on server (online website)..

Comment: @GitsD on the server path should be ok, but on windows often the full path is needed as the dir is not configured to be in the system  path.

Comment: @GitsD: read the manual page for `system`. It will return either the last line of the output or `false`. http://php.net/system

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is check what is going wrong. You might even want to check outside of PHP to see what you are doing. So echo your $command, and look at it, see if it looks correct. Then use it on the commandline, see if you can get it to work.

Possible attention points:

- Do you have any 'strange' characters (like &) in your password? You might need to escape them
- Is the mysqldump command available? (is it in your PATH, or in the dir where you are running this from
- Are you allowed to do any system/exec commands at all?
- Is the user that runs your php code (apache?) allowed to do this command?
- Is the user that runs this code allowed to write in this directory?

To test your current command, you might want to do this:
 - replace your `system` command with an echo: `echo $command;`
 - run the script and copy the command you see there.
 - Open a terminal. (start->run->"cmd")
 - goto the dir where your script is / runs.
 - paste /type the command.
 - check your result.

I do not know what happens when you do not have a password, but still supply the -p option. It might try and ask for a password anyway, as you've indicated you want to enter a password, but have not provided it. I do not know this for sure, that's why you might want to check it. *(@wimvds confirms in the comment: if you supply a -p and no password, you'll get a "password: " dialog.)*

In the commandline you can check what command you need to type to get the mysqldump to work. If that's ok, then make sure your script actually issues that command. Then test again with the script.

Comment: i donot have any password. $username = 'root', $password = '', $hostname = 'localhost'.

Comment: how can i check system/exec commands are allowed or not on my local server using xampp on windows..?

Comment: I've added this to the answer

Comment: If you don't have a password and provide the -p switch with an empty password, then mysqldump will still ask for a password, so either drop the -p or use a valid password...

Comment: check&thanks. added your comment to the answer for clarity :)